# How to uninstall application (AVG)

Tags: mac-pro

I tried to uninstall AVG but kept in saying can't be deleted because it still open, I then went to applications > Utilities and opened up Activity Monitor. Highlight it and click the "Quit Process" button but it comes back straight away and can't delete it.
I can't understand why this is happening.
Please if you can help doooooo.

Comment: Did you try stopping the program using the program itself? If it has a menu at the top right, click it, it should have an option to quit it somewhere.

Comment: Applications like this often have their own Uninstaller. I'd expect it to be located inside the application folder. Typically you can find uninstallation guide from the developers website.

Comment: Note: it's an antivirus's *job* to resist unauthorised attempts to stop it & remove it. That's why they *all* have an uninstaller.

Answer (score 2):

See: [How to uninstall AVG AntiVirus for Mac](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlName=How-to-uninstall-AVG-AntiVirus-for-Mac)

> To uninstall AVG Antivirus for Mac:
>
> 1. Run the AVG AntiVirus for Mac
> 2. Click the **AVG AntiVirus** Menu bar, and click **Uninstall AVG AntiVirus**
> 3. Click **Continue** to begin the uninstallation process
> 4. AVG will run the uninstallation
> 5. The Uninstallation is now complete, please click **Restart** to reboot your computer